# Xcode 11.2.1 codesign error when building react native on a physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am using Xcode 11.2.1 (latest now) to build my iOS react native app (react-native@0.61.4)
The build succeed on any simulator but fails on any physical device (no specific OS version)
Is there any special configuration for the new Xcode - even the react-native template app have the same issue - exit with code 1.

Comment: just check if your build system is legacy

Comment: thank you for your answer, got some improvement - more steps succeeded but failed in the last step - error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 /usr/bin/codesign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure out the issue. It was a code signing issue on the physical device. Simply deleting the old certificates from the keychain access then clean and build did the job.

- From your terminal `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- Go to KeyChain Access and Search for `Apple Development ...` in your KeyChains and delete them, Xcode will then ask for KeyChain password, make sure to check "Always Allow"
- Inside Xcode `Product > Clean (or Clean Build Folder)`
- Build and Run your Project again!

If the error persists you may need to restart your Xcode or even your macbook.

Also, in case of having error with exit code 1, `File > Workspace Settings > Build System: Legacy Build System` may help debugging your issue.

Comment: Answer out of date, unable to change to legacy build system in XCODE 13